# How to set default values mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL version 6.3 and attempted to execute the following syntax:

```
insert into orders(Store_ID, Product_ID, Customer_ID, Quantity, Order_Date)
values (not null, '22','33', '44','2017-03-02');
```

But keep getting the following error response below:

```
Error Code: 1364. Field 'Orders_ID' doesn't have a default value
```

I've read several responses on here, many has extensive feedback...could some one provide solutions to this issue without being too extensive?

Thank you

Comment: how you declare your table structure? what is the type of Orders_ID? because if you want that column has a sequence or something like that you have to say it explicitly..

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are not providing a value for the column, and the column has no *default* to fall back on.

```
ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN Orders_ID SET DEFAULT NULL;
```

Null can be changed to a value you would like.

You can do this

```
ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN Orders_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

This will create a new ID on every insert with an increment of 1 each time.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the table columns are (i.e. string, int, etc.) as well as what it is that you want to put into the Orders_ID column it's hard to say what you should put however I can try to help you once you reply/update your question. :)

I'm guessing the column Orders_ID hasn't got `AUTO-INCREMENT 1` feature set to it so it doesn't automatically increment and add the new Orders_ID when you insert into the Orders table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that you table has a primary key, maybe you can try

```
ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN Orders_ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

About the value of StoreId, you can't insert `NOT NULL` value.

You can check here
[Mysql Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a valid value in your query for the Store_id, as I understand Store_ID is a foreign key from a stores table, so you mus put the id from one store

```
insert into orders (Store_ID, Product_ID, Customer_ID, Quantity, Order_Date)    
values ('13', '22','33', '44','2017-03-02');
```

change 13 for a valid Store_ID